# Find Index Number Of A Specific UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that returns 77 cells. I'm trying to figure out how to point to a specific cell, for instance the cell at row 2, column 4. To boil it down to my very basic need I need to write a statement that would do this:

```
if cell[46] == cell[12] {
println("they match")
}
```

I do not know where to start with this task. I started by trying to print the indexPath that is being used in my `prepareForSegue` method but that's not returning anything.

This collection view is using dynamic cells. Would it any difference to make them static cells?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the method `indexPathForCell(_:)`? It can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/indexPathForCell:). Your question is very ambiguous, at the moment I'm led by the title to assume you just want to find the `indexPath` property of the cell. But then I'm also led to believe you want to compare the data in the cell by your question. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: In your if-statement, you are comparing the cells. How do you want to compare them? By the data they contain? If so, you should consider comparing your data source rather than the cell they are displayed in.

Comment: @jkaufman I don't want to get the the index path of each of the cells. I need to know what each of their indexes is. There must be a logical grouping. Like if you have 11 cells on a screen the first one is `collectionview.cell[0]` the second one is `collectionview.cell[1]`.

Comment: @Ian It's a visual comparison. Each cell is filled with data but comparing the data source I believe would be too cumbersome and would ping the server excessively. If a user inputs in `cell[1]` and then inputs in `cell[8]`, which is at it's caddy-corner, the cells need to reset and then reload with new data from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists `collectionView?.visibleCells()` which returns `[AnyObject]` which you can cast to be of type `UICollectionViewCell` so you can get an array of on screen cells. Then you can access specific cells using subscript notation for comparison, but I still don't think directly comparing the cells is the best approach and if you can store your data in such a way that you can easily access the values without making a request to the server each time, that would be a much better approach for what you're attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @jkaufman, you need to use a method that gets you a cell from an index path. `func cellForItemAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell?` is the method you would need, and you can pass it an index path, which can be constructed with a section and row index. From there, you could get each of your cells, and do the comparison after retrieving both cells from the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Function documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/cellForItemAtIndexPath: